# Optimize an index in select mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a dating website and for years I've tried to optimize this query. Almost everyday the site gets stuck because of it.

User table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `longitude` float(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `birth_year` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1997',
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `gender_search` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `minimum_age` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '18',
  `maximum_age` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '80',
  `unix_timestamp_online` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_blocked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Indexes

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `multiple_index`(
    `unix_timestamp_online`,
    `user_blocked`,
    `gender`,
    `gender_search`,
    `maximum_age`,
    `minimum_age`,
    `birth_year`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`
) USING BTREE;
```

Query example

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude 
FROM users 
WHERE gender=2 
AND id NOT IN (11111111,2222222) 
AND (birth_year BETWEEN 1961 AND 1999) 
AND (latitude BETWEEN -25.14 AND -16.13) 
AND (longitude BETWEEN -54.87 AND -45.86) 
AND user_blocked=0 
AND minimum_age<=35 
AND maximum_age>=35 
AND gender_search IN(0,1) 
ORDER BY unix_timestamp_online DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Summarizing the conditions of the sample query..

- I am `male=1` and search `female=2`
- Exclude some `ids`
- Born `between 1961 AND 1999`
- In `latitude, longitude`...
- Does not have any type of `block=0`
- My `age=35` must be acceptable to these users
- My gender also needs to be acceptable (`all=0, male=1`)
- Order by displaying users who are `online` first

Explain the example query

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: users
partitions: NULL
type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: multiple_index
key_len: 19
ref: NULL
rows: 20
filtered: 0.25
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

This query takes an average of 0.0020 seconds

If I change the birth_year condition to (`BETWEEN 1999 AND 1999`)

The explanation is identical and the query takes an average of 9.1376 seconds

This multiple index does not look pretty, but it was the best so far. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That average is calculated with sql_no_cache?

Comment: Incidentally, the numbers in parentheses on your integer columns have almost no meaning

Comment: Strawberry. How do I know if sql_no_cache is used?

Comment: Strawberry. id NOT IN (11111111,2222222)? Are ids that will be excluded from queries, the current user id for example, can not be in the result, admin id too.

Comment: The execution time will depend on your data. For your slow query, only a very small percentage of your users will fulfill your condition (females born in 1999). You can optimize your current index a bit if you use `gender, user_blocked, unix_timestamp_online, ... the rest`. How much this speeds up your query will depend on how many female users you have (e.g. 10% female users = about 90% faster). But in general, you may need to adapt your data to optimize your search (as searching is likely the main feature of your site), e.g. using precalculated lists, valueclusters, a lot of indexes, ...

Comment: You would know because you would have typed "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE rest of query..."  and I'm not talking about *those* parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

why not do the query like this, using the simpler conditions before the complex ones.

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude 
FROM users 
WHERE gender=2 
AND user_blocked=0 
AND minimum_age<=35 
AND maximum_age>=35 
AND gender_search IN(0,1)
AND id NOT IN (11111111,2222222) 
AND (birth_year BETWEEN 1961 AND 1999) 
AND (latitude BETWEEN -25.14 AND -16.13) 
AND (longitude BETWEEN -54.87 AND -45.86) 
ORDER BY unix_timestamp_online DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: By organization or the order of conditions change the time of the result?

Comment: it should, why not try it first, the condition in that query is too long, organising it to simpler ones should reduce its stress, e.g filter out users with gender =2 , user_blocked = 0 before considering id not in 11111111, 22222222.